# AngularJS making a sum between objects

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am quite new to AngularJS and have been building the following:

app.js

```
$scope.inkomsten= [
    { name: 'Salaris',value:'500' },
    { name: 'Toeslag',value:'200' },
    { name: 'Inkomsten',value:'211' },
    { name: 'Weekend', value:'22' }
];

$scope.uitgiften= [
    {   name: 'eten',value:'120'},
    { name: 'kat',value:'230'},
    { name: 'schildpad', value: '300'},
    { name: 'huur', value: '200'}
];
```

Now I would like to take the values of both of these object and substract them from each other! 
So either have all the values of `Inkomsten` added to another and the ones from `Uitgiften`.. and then substract or individually(Which is prefered... So taking the value of `uitgiften` and then from `inkomsten` and substract them.)

I have been tinkering around with it but I can't seem to find a solution for it. Anyways, not in Angular :D

I hope you guys can help

---

Clarification:

Sorry. I would like to have

```
uitgiften.value[1]+uitgiften.value[2]+uitgiften.value[3]
and then inkomsten.value[1]+inkomsten.value[2]+inkomsten.value[3]
```

and then the outcome of these 2 summs would need to be `outcomeInkomsten-outcomeUitgiften=endOutcome`

Comment: subtract or add like what ?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I've edited a clearification on the bottom of the original post

Answer (score 0):

Since your values are strings, you will need to cast them to numbers. Here's what I would do:

```
var result = 0;
$scope.inkomsten.forEach(function(item){
  result += Number(item.value);
});
$scope.uitgiften.forEach(function(item){
  result -= Number(item.value);
});
```

Comment: @MartijnBos please let us know if any of these answers helped

Answer (score 0):

you can use array method reduce:

```js
var $scope={};
$scope.inkomsten= [
    { name: 'Salaris',value:'500' },
    { name: 'Toeslag',value:'200' },
    { name: 'Inkomsten',value:'211' },
    { name: 'Weekend', value:'22' }
];

var res = $scope.inkomsten.reduce(function(total, current){
    return total + Number(current.value);
}, 0)

console.log(res)
```

this will give you the numeric total of an Array;

and then you can do the same with second array, and subtract the two;

Answer (score 0):

well you can use

```
var results=0;
for(i=0;i<$scope.inkomsten.length;i++){
      results+=Number($scope.inkomsten[i].value);
}
for(i=0;i<$scope.uitgiften.length;i++){
      results-=Number($scope.uitgiften[i].value);
}
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an array you could add a function to the Array prototype.

```
$scope.inkomsten= [
   { name: 'Salaris',value:'500' },
   { name: 'Toeslag',value:'200' },
   { name: 'Inkomsten',value:'211' },
   { name: 'Weekend', value:'22' }
];

$scope.uitgiften= [
   { name: 'eten',value:'120'},
   { name: 'kat',value:'230'},
   { name: 'schildpad', value: '300'},
   { name: 'huur', value: '200'}
];

Array.prototype.sum = function (prop) {
    var total = 0;
    for ( var i = 0, _len = this.length; i < _len; i++ ) {
        total += parseInt(this[i][prop]);
    }
    return total;
}

$scope.endOutcome = $scope.inkomsten.sum("value") - $scope.uitgiften.sum("value");
```

The Fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/20778/

Comment: Looks great! Even though I am not sure where this _len suddenly comes from. Would you care to explain the for loop? (If you would like to?)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this below code

```
$scope.inkomsten= [
       { name: 'Salaris',value:'500' },
       { name: 'Toeslag',value:'200' },
       { name: 'Inkomsten',value:'211' },
       { name: 'Weekend', value:'22' }
    ];
$scope.uitgiften= [
       { name: 'eten',value:'120'},
       { name: 'kat',value:'230'},
       { name: 'schildpad', value: '300'},
       { name: 'huur', value: '200'}
    ];

$scope.sum1 = 0;
$scope.sum2 = 0;

for(i in $scope.inkomsten){
    $scope.sum1 = $scope.sum1 + parseInt($scope.inkomsten[i].value);
}

for(i in $scope.uitgiften){
    $scope.sum2 = $scope.sum2 + parseInt($scope.uitgiften[i].value);
}

$scope.endOutcome = $scope.sum1 - $scope.sum2;

alert($scope.endOutcome);
```

Comment: Looks fantastic. I get what is happening in the code you wrote and will most likely try to replicate it from mind :) Thank you for the insight.